# Help to decipher Russian names written in Chinese characters

Tags: translation, transliteration

I am researching Chinese plant scientists in the 1950s. A friend sent a text translated from Mandarin with names of two Russian scientists transliterated from the Mandarin characters for me.  Neither he, nor I can guess what the original Russian names would be.

The Russian names were given as the characters:
Kuo Fei Er Ge
and
Rein Fei Er Ge

Grateful for anyone who could hazard a guess at the Russian names.

The scientists visited China in 1952 to advise on a citrus disease, but I cannot find publications or conference attendee lists from that period.

Comment: Do you know the characters? That would help.

Comment: Sorry, no. They were translated by someone else a long time ago.

Comment: @Mo. "Kuofeierge" is "阔菲尔格". https://engine.scichina.com/publisher/scp/journal/CSB/4/12/10.1360/csb1953-0-12-42?slug=abstract

Comment: Can't find "Rein Fei Er Ge" because there's no "rein" in Mandarin Chinese Pinyin. Also, "阔菲尔格" is not as famous as Vavilov or Michurin, so I searched on Baidu and Bing for many times, but no result.

Comment: Some thoughts: the two names are very similar, could they be relatives (eg brothers) and first character be the abbreviation of their first name, like K. and R. "Feierge"? Do you have context what exactly they researched so you can search for publications on that topic (likely only be in Russian and Chinese)? Also, perhaps the history of science Stackexchange is a good place to ask?

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen It seem not. According to that paper, "阔菲尔格" is a surname, not a surname and a first name. Maybe there are some Chinese on History of Science StackExchange, but the others can't understand Chinese Characters :-/

Answer (score 1):

the link provided in the 3rd comment has two russian name mentioned:

“華西列夫”, which would be “vasilev”, “vasilyev”, “vasiliev” or “vassiliev”

another one is “闊菲爾格”

the place they visited was “黃岩”, the trees was “citrus”

https://baike.sogou.com/v141878.htm

http://www.05760576.com/2006/11/23/133442357.html

one more russian expert’s name: “柯魯索夫”

have fun :)